# Java sum a list of items based on their properties

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a list of results :

```java
List<Score> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each of the elements of this list contains values like :

```java
int score_id, int competition_id, date date, String discipline, String category, 
            int player_id, String player_fname, String player_lname, int referee_id,
            String referee_fname, String referee_lname, float points
```

```sql
score_id | competition_id | date | discipline | category | player_id | player_fname |player_lname | referee_id | referee_fname | referee_lname | points
    1           1       2020-06-05   Skiing      Sprint        1          Simon      Bird               1           John             Snow          15
    2           1       2020-06-05   Skiing      Sprint        1          Simon      Bird               2           James            Luck          15
```

How can I filter the List and Sum points based on player_id and competition_id?

Or use a query to insert this data to a table after points are summed.

The final result should be like :

```sql
competition_id | date | discipline | category | player_id | player_fname | player_lname | points | place
      1      2020-06-05  Skiing      Sprint         1           Simon           Bird         30       1
      1      2020-06-05  Skiing      Sprint         2           George         Clooney       27       2
      1      2020-06-05  Skiing      Sprint         3           Julia          Roberts       24       3
```

Comment: Do you want do this in Java or in a query with Hibernate?

Comment: I thought about doing it to java then transferring to database, but I think query would be even better

Comment: So please tell us what exactly you want to do. Do you know SQL?

Comment: I need a query to sum all of the points a player got in competition from referees. Updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got it I just hope It won't be a temporary answer

So I've made a query that works :

```sql
SELECT competition_id, data, discipline, category, player_id, playerFirstName, playerLastName, SUM(points) as points
FROM    javadatabase.score
GROUP BY  competition_id, player_id
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Comment: How can I now use this query in hibernate to store all that info into a table?

Comment: Why do you want to store that in a table?

Comment: I tried Insert into () select ..... but It dont work. However i managed to put all of these objects into a List<Object[]> now is it now possible to go through that list and add each line to a new Results object?

Comment: ```List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT s.competition_id, s.data, s.discipline, s.category, s.player_id," + " s.playerFirstName, s.playerLastName, SUM(s.points) as points FROM Score s"
+ " GROUP BY s.competition_id, s.player_id "
+ " ORDER BY s.points DESC", Object[].class).getResultList();```

Comment: Now I have a class entity Results and now I need to send each line of data from ```List<Object[]>results``` into ```Results result = new result(); ``` and then persist transaction and commit it and it should work.

Comment: Do you know how to do that ?